# identify the patterns in image without template matching in an image python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, deep-learning

I have thousands of image and each image there is multiple pattern , want to automatically identify and classify the patterns in the image .
one sample is as below

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

In this image there is 3 patterns say p1, p2 and p3. So how to identify the patterns automatically , and after that if same pattern is present in next image then it should classify those patterns if new pattern comes it should identify those also .
Any idea how to proceed for this task

Comment: Go through Discrete Cosine Transform

Comment: @JeruLuke tried that but not able to identify and classify the patterns in image ,can u give a small example

Comment: It would be great if you could share what you have tried. Just edit the question to add the update.

Comment: @JeruLuke not getting how to use DCT ..just can convert gray scale image to DCT , i have pated the code in pastebin have a look https://pastebin.com/xsMBrpQR

Comment: is this Game Of Life, an analysis of a binary file, or did you show us something you filtered already? showing us untouched source data would help you the most.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz hey i am reallly blank at this point how to proceed any end to end solution not able to figure out how to proceed , really stucked

Comment: the provided image is the real one no filetration has been done on it @ChristophRackwitz

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz How to identify multiple pattern and classify in single image , because all the images have multiple patterns presnt inside that

Comment: You want to extract unknown patterns? How do you define pattern? Some repeating element? Any assumptions or limitations available?

Comment: Maybe have a look at the field of texture analysis. Probably it's a long way for an end to end solution, but there might be a chance with fourier transform or gabor filter banks and some smart clustering.

Comment: @Micka yes want to extract all the patterns , no assumption or limitation is there the image provided is real one .